# Explanations about a Flex binding issue?

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding

I have a class similar to the following one:

```
[Bindable]
public class BindableClass
{
    private var _provider:ArrayList;

    public function BindableClass()
    {
    }

    public function get provider():ArrayList{
        return _provider;
    }

    public function set provider(value:ArrayList):void {
        _provider= value;
    }

}
```

Let's assume `provider` contains an array of BindableClasses as well. I'm trying to set `{BindableClass(bindableClassInstance.provider.getItemAt(0)).provider}` as the source of a List dataProvider, but it isn't detecting any change in an element inside my inner provider list.

Making `{new ArrayList([BindableClass(bindableClassInstance.provider.getItemAt(0)).provider.source])}` does work tho.

I'm already binding bindableClassInstance at another place, is that a problem? Why is this happening? Could not find an explanation around.

I tried to use the -keep compiler argument, but for some reason it's not generating all the code of my complete application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized which was the issue, the inner provider list was filled by accessing its inner array.